# How to add a Windows Security dialogue to a Java Web Application

Tags: java, security, web-applications

Sometimes I see the following sort of dialogue asking for username / password. I was wondering is there anyway we can add this to a java web application

[image: Window Security dialogue]

Comment: Adding to the above : This dialogue appears when few web applications are accessed. The similar i see when i access tomcat manager / admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog that you are seeing appear to be coming from a web application integrated with Windows Security.  Following are the couple of ways you can do it in java realm.

1. [Standard Apache recommended way](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html).
2. [Using a open source Spnego Lib](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/)

This might be confusing with  **Basic-Authentication** (Check *Configuring Basic Authentication* [Here](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html) ) it also presents a *similar* dialog box but its NOT same as above.